# iOS: Has granted permission?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

Is there a Core Location object that we can ask to see if the user has granted the app the right to give their location?

Currently we have to check to see if the location object's Coordinate IsValid each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `CLLocationManager`'s `+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus` method. It's since iOS 4.2 and tells you the app's authorisation state.

- http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus